# Intellisense warning that it can't find function definition for assembly function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, intellisense, extern

In my MSVC 2015 project I have a function, `int foo(int, int)` which is implemented in an .asm file. When I `extern "C"` declare this function in a .cpp file in the same project, Intellisense complains that `Function definition for 'foo' not found.`:

[image: screenshot of Intellisense warning]

I'm at a loss for why Intellisense believes it could in general find definitions for extern functions - plenty of these will be declared in dlls, static libraries, or other binary formats without source available at compile-time, not to mention my .asm (compiled to .obj as part of the project build) file case.

I should mention that the project builds fine and `foo()` is called without issue.

What is Intellisense's beef here, and how to resolve it?